# Iron powder reaction in chlorate candle

Tags: iss, oxygen, combustion

When a sodium chlorate candle is ignighted, the iron powder is burned to allow the oxygen to be released with the reaction 
2NaClO3 → 2NaCl + 3O2

The iron powder is not included in this equation, and I was wondering what its combustion reaction is, as according to the equation above all of the oxygen is released as a gas. I was wondering what the reaction scheme for the iron is.

Comment: I think you have posted in the wrong Stack Exchange site. There are almost 200 different ones. Have a look at [Chemistry Stack Exchange](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions) for this question. This is Space Exploration.

Comment: @uhoh Agree that this probably belongs on Chem.sx but such candles are used by the Russian program for emergency oxygen supply. (A malfunctioning one started the fire on Mir.)

Comment: @RussellBorogove I've retracted my close vote, maybe this can be shaped up into a better question here, and a separate chemistry question can be asked as well.

Comment: Welcome to *Space!*  I agree with uhoh that you will get a better answer in Chemistry.SE.  If you still wish to edit your question to make it fit here better, could you do that in the next 24 hours?  Thanks!

Comment: While it's absolutely possible to ask a chemistry question that is so thoroughly about space exploration that it belongs on this site, I don't believe *this* question, in its current form, is such a question. There are any number of other applications for sodium chlorate candles, and the relevance of space is basically nil (it's not in a vacuum and microgravity presumably does quite little?).